# Dynamically change page that loads

Tags: pages, page-template

I'm trying to figure out how I can change the page that loads. Let's assume I'm just using the default permalink and I have a URL with a page_id. I want to be able to override the page that would normally load and load a different page based on some logic that I will maintain.

I've dug through a bunch of the files and I cannot seem to figure out where I can catch the page_id and override it.

I will admit I'm not all that experienced with WP development so I'm not really sure what I am doing. I'm just looking for some direction here to make sure this is even possible.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: can you edit the question and specify the conditions you are interested in? Otherwise there are actually too many ways to do that to list them all.

Comment: I've posted an answer but it may be off base. If so, please give more information and I'll try and help further.

Answer (score 1):

Wp load pages based on it's main query.

SO if you want to load a different page, then you may have to alter the main query with th e pre_get_posts hook.If you want to know more.Then please specif what and how you want to load different page in details

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't particularly clear I'm afraid, but it sounds to me like you are trying to override the default template.  For example, you still want the contents of your page to be displayed, but you don't want to use the default **page.php** template.

If I am correct (please let me know in the comments if not), then there are two ways to do this.

---

## Override using the Template Hierarchy

If, for example, you have only one page that you wish to display using a different template you can simply name that **page-$slug.php** or **page-$id.php**.

For example, if you have a page called **Example Page** with a slug of **example** and an ID of **10**, you could create a template called either **page-example.php** or **page-10.php**.

For more information on this please see the [Codex for the WordPress Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy).

---

## Override using the 'template_include' filter

If the first method is no good for you there is another way.

Using the 'template_include' filter you can check which page is about to be displayed and, if you desire, change the template that will be used.

For more information, please see the [Filter Reference for `template_include`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include).

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'portfolio_page_template', 99 );
function portfolio_page_template( $template ) {

    if ( is_page( 'portfolio' )  ) {
        $new_template = locate_template( array( 'portfolio-page-template.php' ) );
        if ( '' != $new_template ) {
            return $new_template ;
        }
    }

    return $template;
}
```